# opencv Mat memory access error

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to write a function to compensate lens vignetting in an OpenCV project.  The problem is that when I attempt to access the first pixel in the Mat, I get a memory access error.  It's probably a silly error, but I'd appreciate it if you could point it out to me.  Here's the function:

```
void EckOpCam::FlatField(cv::Mat & parmI)
{
// workaround for access violation error
cv::Mat I = parmI;
const int channels = I.channels();
if (flatField.rows == 0)
    MakeFlatFieldMat(I.rows);
// accept only char type matrices
ASSERT(I.depth() == CV_8U);
// make sure the matrices are the same size
ASSERT(I.cols == flatField.cols);
ASSERT(channels == flatField.channels());


// Try the really slow way...
int nRows = I.rows;
int nCols = I.cols;
unsigned int ipix0, ipix1, ipix2;   // B,G,r values of pixel in I
float fpix0, fpix1,fpix2;           // B,G,r values of pixel in flatField
float pix0, pix1, pix2;
switch (channels)
{
case 1:
    for (int y = 0; y < nRows; ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < nCols; ++x)
        {
            {
                ipix0 = I.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[0];
                fpix0 = flatField.at<cv::Vec3f>(x, y)[0];
                pix0 = ipix0 * fpix0;
                I.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[0] = (pix0 > 255) ? 255 : uchar(pix0);
            }
        }
    break;
case 3:
    for (int y = 0; y < nRows; ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < nCols; ++x)
        {
            {
                ipix0 = static_cast<uchar>(I.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[0]); //<<< memory access error!
                ipix1 = static_cast<uchar>(I.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[1]);
                ipix2 = static_cast<uchar>(I.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[2]);
                fpix0 = flatField.at<cv::Vec3f>(x, y)[0];
                fpix1 = flatField.at<cv::Vec3f>(x, y)[1];
                fpix2 = flatField.at<cv::Vec3f>(x, y)[2];
                pix0 = ipix0 * fpix0;
                pix1 = ipix1 * fpix1;
                pix2 = ipix2 * fpix2;
                I.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[0] = (pix0 > 255) ? 255 : uchar(pix0);
                I.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[1] = (pix1 > 255) ? 255 : uchar(pix1);
                I.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[2] = (pix2 > 255) ? 255 : uchar(pix2);
            }
        }
}
```

}

The error is: Exception thrown: read access violation.
cv::Vec::operator returned 0x240C37EC4A8.

The address given is exactly the address for I.data.  What's wrong?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: `cv::Mat & parmI` do you really need to pass by reference. Assignment of Mat class is already a pointer assignment anyway.

Comment: Isn't what you're doing basically a per-element multiplication with saturation? As in `I = I.mul(flatField);` instead of all that code?

Comment: @macroland:  Yes, pass by reference is required.  I tried to pass by value and got no image back.

Comment: @Dan: I'd love to use I.mul.  Unfortunately, the image is CV_8UC3 and the flatField matrix is CV_32FC3.  I'll try converting the image to CV_32FC3, using I32.mul(flatField) and converting back.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @dr_eck Oh, I missed that floating point type. Nevertheless, `cv::multiply` also performs per-element multiplication with saturation and lets you explicitly specify the result type. So `cv::multiply(I, flatField, I, 1.0, CV_8UC3);`

Comment: @Dan:  Thanks for following up.  I have a working solution now, but I'll try your suggestion when I get time to refactor.  On to the next feature!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um... Never mind.  It turned out that the exception was real and not a problem with this code.  I am using sample code from Point Grey.  It converts from a Point Grey ImagePtr to a Mat using a Mat constructor that just copies the pointer to the data.  The ImagePtr went out of scope, so the data was invalid when I attempted to use it.  Mat.CopyTo() solved the problem.  I highly recommend reading [this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html) if you need a fast way to solve a similar problem.